# How to sanitize html with HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm facing a problem in my webscraper, essentially I need to get the decimal number inside the cell `team_a_col home`:

```
<th>Med. goal subiti p/p</th>
<td class='team_a_col total'>0.76</td>
<td class='team_a_col home'>0.89
<td class='team_a_col away'>0.62</td></td>
```

so the result should be: 0.89

but as you can see the `html` have a bad structure, so instead of get `0.89` I get also the content of `team_a_col away` with this code:

```
node.SelectSingleNode(".//td[@class='team_a_col home']").InnerText.Trim();
```

How can I get only 0.89? The `</td>` should be before of `<team_a_col away`..

Comment: What is the code you use now?

Comment: @rene `node.SelectSingleNode(".//td[@class='team_a_col home']").InnerText.Trim();`

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack is old and broken, rather use [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp). As for malformed HTML, there is nothing any library can do about it except a best effort - you are probably going to have to handle it manually yourself.

Comment: @IanKemp I can't change the library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set  `HtmlDocument.FixNestedTags` to `true`:

```
string html = "<th>Med. goal subiti p/p</th><td class='team_a_col total'>0.76</td><td class='team_a_col home'>0.89<td class='team_a_col away'>0.62</td></td>";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
{
    OptionFixNestedTags = true,
    OptionCheckSyntax = true,
    OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true
};
doc.LoadHtml(html);

string tdText = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//td[@class='team_a_col home']")?.InnerText.Trim();
```

With `FixNestedTags` the result is: `0.89`

Answer (score 0):

Could you just take whole line and then substring and fetch the data?

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//htmlelment/htmlelment");

string[] nodeArray = node[0].OuterHtml.Split(' ');
```